# Data Set edit/refresh fails after being migrated to another user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I have the following issue in AWS QuickSight: A user created a dataset through Athena. Everything worked fine. The user shared the dataset with another user granting him OWNER rights. Then the first user was deleted. Now the second user can't edit the dataset anymore. He can share it but the person it is shared to can't edit it either. The error message:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a mess to be honest. The data sources in QuickSight are connected to the user who created it. They inherit their access roles from whoever created them. This is not accessible through the API though I think it is mentioned in the documentation somewhere. Thus it can't be changed.

So when we deleted the users who originally created the data sources they ceased working along with the data sets based on them.

Our solution for this was that we created "standard" data sources with a technical user - this was not such a big deal because we exclusively use Athena - and then recreated all the data sets and switched them to the new standard data sources - this was a big deal because analysts had to switch data sets in their analysis / dashboards.

To me this shows that QuickSight is not quite complete as a analytics platform in large companies. The API is not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can be solved by the Quicksight account Admin using the Quicksight UI to add dataset editing permission to this user [as shown here](https://learnquicksight.workshop.aws/en/admin-workshop/6.custom-permissions.html).

Or it may well be that the new Owner does not have the required IAM permissions such as `quicksight:UpdateDataSet` IAM permission, [see the docs](https://aws.permissions.cloud/iam/quicksight).

What does it say when you click the "Show details" link in the screenshot above?